# Lookup Field Icon Doesn't Show Up On Sites

Tags: force.com-sites, lookup

I am developing a site under my organization and a Case Management panel in it. I prepared a page called NewCase and basicaly built a template that includes Case fields in it. But lookup fields doesn't show up with their icons but just the label and input box. So I can not set lookup field values.

Do you have any ideas what should I do?

Note: I've added Lookup Page to site's Standard Pages.

UPDATE: Code section (SerialNo__c is a custom lookup field related a custom object.)

`<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Case.Fields.SerialNo__c.Label}" for="serialNo" />
<apex:inputField value="{!newCase.SerialNo__c}" id="serialNo"/>`

Comment: Are you able to view the icon within the salesforce env? is it just not visible on sites? Do you have some code for us to view

Comment: Yes Prady, I can see the icon within the Salesforce environment. I've set field level security on Sites Profile. By the way, I've added code section the post.

Comment: though i havent used lookups on public sites, my guess is that icons should be visible. You would need to allow access to the lookup page for sites profile for the lookup page to be visible. but the icons should be visible even if you dont provide access to the lookup page.. Is there something in your css which is hiding the icon?

Comment: I've already allowed Lookup Page for sites. There is no CSS to hide icon.

Answer (score 3):

If your VF page has standardStylesheets="false" then the button won't show up next to the input box. I copied this from salesforce common.css to use in my pages that don't use the standard style sheets.

/* Salesforce css for lookup button */

```
.lookupInput
{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.lookupInput img
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: .25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.lookupInput .disabled
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.lookupInput .emptyDependentLookup
{
    font-style: italic;
}
.lookupInput input[readonly]
{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
    color: #333;
    cursor: default;
}
.lookupInput a.readOnly
{
    float: right;
}
.lookupInput span.readOnly
{
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
}
.lookupInput span.totalSummary
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.inlineEditRequiredDiv .lookupInput img,.inlineEditDiv .lookupInput img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.quickCreateModule .lookupInput input {
    max-width: 155px
}
.lookupIcon {
    background-image: url(/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif);
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: top left
}
.lookupIconOn {
    background-image: url(/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif);
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: top right
}
```